# Running a python subprocess in Flask

Tags: flask, scrapy, subprocess

I have a Flask web app running a crawling process in this fashion:

**on terminal tab 1:**

```
$ cd /path/to/scraping
$ scrapyrt
```

> [http://scrapyrt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html](http://scrapyrt%20documentation)

**on terminal tab 2:**

```
$ python app.pp
```

and in `app.py`:

```
params = {
          'spider_name': spider,
          'start_requests':True
          }

        response = requests.get('http://localhost:9080/crawl.json', params)
        print ('RESPONSE',response)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
```

which works.

---

now I'de like to move everthing into `app.py`, and for that I've tried:

```
        import subprocess
        from time import sleep

        try:
            subprocess.check_output("scrapyrt", shell=True, cwd='path/to/scraping')
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))

        sleep(3)

params = {
          'spider_name': spider,
          'start_requests':True
           }

        response = requests.get('http://localhost:9080/crawl.json', params)
        print ('RESPONSE',response)
        data = json.loads(response.text)
```

this starts twisted, like so:

```
2018-02-03 17:29:35-0200 [-] Log opened.
2018-02-03 17:29:35-0200 [-] Site starting on 9080
2018-02-03 17:29:35-0200 [-] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x104effa70>
```

but crawling process hangs and does not go through.

what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using a scheduler, such as APScheduler or similar?
You can run code using crons or in intervals, and it integrates well with Flask.

Take a look here:
http://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userguide.html

Here is an example:

```
from flask import Flask
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

app = Flask(__name__)
cron = BackgroundScheduler()
cron.start()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@cron.scheduled_job('interval', minutes=3)
def my_scrapper():
    # Do the stuff you need
    return True
```

Comment: could you please be more specific?

Comment: So the code which is executed under "Tab 1" can go into a function of the Flask app file. Then, the code can be set to execute using APScheduler at desired intervals in the same. Only the Flask app is running, and executing the scraping code.